# Log in Alarm manager running repeatedly at IntentService

Tags: android

I'm using an Intent Service-Myintentservice.java. In that i have placed an alarm manager to start the same intent service at specified time..when i created log in that it runs continuously in milliseconds till the start time reached after it has stopped.

Code:

```
public class Myintentservice extends IntentService{

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

if(within start and end time){
 .....Do the required task....
}  
else
{
  am1=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  Intent locup=new Intent(this,Myintentservice.class);
  locupIntent=PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,locup, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   Log.i("locup", "postinginterval-->"+Integer.toString(point));
   Log.i("ctalarm", "trigger time-->"+Long.toString(hms.getTimeInMillis()));
  am1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, hms.getTimeInMillis(), point, locupIntent);
 }
 }
 }
```

I have included the if..else statement in onHandleIntent method.If the start time and end time are between the current time IF part will execute otherwise go to ELSE part and execute again when start time reached..have passed the start time to hms.getTimeInMillis() in set repeating alarm..

service starts and end at specified time but my question is whether the service or alarm manager running the log which i created above till the start time reached?Is there any possibilities to stop that service OR alarm and start at specified time..?

Comment: what's happening today with questions related to seconds, miliseconds,...¿¿¿??

Comment: @ Asier Aranbarri:What's the problem with u?

Comment: did you even bother to type www.google.com on your browser? Regards.